# How to remove themes?

Tags: 11.10, themes

How do I completely remove a theme in Ubuntu?

I want to remove the Ambiance and Radiance themes, I am using Adwaita as a replacement and also I am using GNOME.

Using Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the package `light-themes` in Ubuntu 11.10 to get right of these two themes.

As per the package description:

```
 Light Themes (Ambiance and Radiance)
 Includes matching Ambiance and Radiance themes

 * Ambiance is a light-on-dark theme
 * Radiance is a dark-on-light theme

 Introduced as the default themes in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
```

### WARNING:

If you remove this package, please do it at your own risk. This will remove the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage which is useful for updating from one 11.10 to 12.04

**Geeky details:**

```
manish@Blackbeast:~$  aptitude why light-themes
i   ubuntu-artwork Depends light-themes
manish@Blackbeast:~$ aptitude why ubuntu-artwork
i   ubuntu-desktop Depends ubuntu-artwork
```

Comment: so after removing these themes, if i install ubuntu-desktop using sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop then?

Comment: If you install `ubuntu-desktop` after removing this package, then the package `light-themes` will be reinstalled as `light-themes` is a dependency of `ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: ok, thanks, can you tell me how to change the ubuntu boot splash screen? I tried changing it but only the shutdown theme got changed

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115918/change-the-ubuntu-boot-splash-screen

Comment: Keep the discussion of that question there. If you find this answer correct, please mark it as Correct.